# ZIP download contains html content

Tags: c#, .net, download

When I use the following code to download a ZIP file it appears to work. However, when I attempt to open the downloaded ZIP, I get an 'invalid compressed folder' message. When I open the ZIP in notepad I see it is filled with HTML.

```
string fp = Server.MapPath("directory\\file.zip");
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fp);

if (file.Exists)
{
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
    Response.AddHeader("content-length", file.Length.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
    Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
    Response.End();
}
```

An issue I can't seem to fix that is probably related is when I try to manually type in the address of the file (`http://website.com/downloads/file.zip`), I get a redirect (`http://website.com/login.aspx`) even when logged in as the admin. Any pointers in where to look would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does the HTML represent? the login form? an error page? or...

Comment: It creates a generic error page.

Comment: and what's the error message?

Comment: I'll have to turn on tracing and run it again. Right now it just has the generic 'there was an error' message.

Comment: since the error message tells you what the exception was and provides the location (stack trace) that seems like mighty fine idea

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just using `Response.ClearContent()` also use `Response.ClearHeaders()` to remove all the current headers as well as the body of the response.

From MSDN, [HttpResponse.ClearContent Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.clearcontent.aspx):

> The ClearContent method does not clear header information.

Comment: @Jesse - Did you check the content of the HTML? If it is an error message, it could have clues.